# Sybase ASE doing showplan for all requests

Tags: sybase, jdbc

We have a strange situation where we are seeing showplan information in packets returned from a Sybase ASE 12.5 database server to a JDBC client. ie using tcpdump we see showplan output being sent back. We are trying to avoid this as the database is performing badly and it can't help having to generate detailed plan information.

We can't see any configuration settings client-side which would make this the case - is there some setting server-side which forces this option to be on?

Answer (score 1):

`SET SHOWPLAN [ON|OFF]` is a session-level command in Sybase ASE, it's not a server-level setting (if it was a server-level setting you'd be able to alter it via `sp_configure`). Can you run wireshark (or something similar) on the packets being sent from the JDBC client to see if it's setting showplan on as part of the session initialization?

That said - showing the plan should not affect database CPU or memory usage, the plan is generated by the query optimiser anyway. However, showing the plan will increase network utilization.

Comment: Completely agree with Mr. Simon on his answer however have noticed performance degradation if showplan is enabled for a certain query. For troubleshooting and checking detailed level, enabling showplan is absolutely fine however keeping it always on is not a good option. There are two settings - one is for process plan and second is query time statistics. there must be some setting which is enabling them by default.